# Can I use dojo.validate.us.isSocialSecurityNumber in a Spring Web Flow Project?

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo, spring-webflow

Can I use dojo.validate.us.isSocialSecurityNumber in a Spring Web Flow Project?  I am trying to make a Soical Security field in my Spring web flow project but the following code dont work?  How should I make a SSN file with dijit?

```
<form:input path="name" class="value" /> <script
                            type="text/javascript">
                        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
                            elementId : "name",
                            widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox",
                            widgetAttrs : {
                                promptMessage : "US Social Security Number",
                                invalidMessage : "Invalid US Social Security Number.",
                                required : true,
                                validator: "dojo.validate.us.isSocialSecurityNumber()",
                                trim : true
                            }
                        }));
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use it like this `validator: dojox.validate.us.isSocialSecurityNumber` no parenthesis, no quotes.

you also need `dojo.require("dojox.validate.us");`

so this is what you should use, based on your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojox.validate.us");
    Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
        elementId : "name",
        widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox",
        widgetAttrs : {
            promptMessage : "US Social Security Number",
            invalidMessage : "Invalid US Social Security Number.",
            required : true,
            validator: dojox.validate.us.isSocialSecurityNumber,
            trim : true
            }
        }));
</script>
```